# Pet.Acropromazine(): Not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a class for a pet name, age, weight and if it is a dog or cat and the have to methods to calculate the dosage for Aceptomazine and Carprofen. I want to return a different value for both the Aceptomazine and Carprofen method for a cat and a dog but when I do it says Pet.Acropromazine: not all code paths return a value and the same error for the Carprofen method. I am not sure why it's doing this.
any help would be appericated

```
 class Pet
{
    private string mName;
    private int mAge;
    private double mWeight;
    private string mType;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return mName; }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) )
            {
                mName = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Name cannot be empty");
            }
        }
    }
    public int Age
    {
        get { return mAge; }
        set
        {
            if (value > 1)
            {
                mAge = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Age must be greater than 1");
            }
        }
    }

    public double Weight
    {
        get { return mWeight; }
        set
        {
            if (value > 5)
            {
                mWeight = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Age must be greater than 5");
            }
        }
    }



    public Pet()
    {
        mName = "Super Pet";
        mType = "Dog";
        mAge = 1;
        mWeight = 5;

        }
    public double Acropromazine()
    {
        if (mType == "Dog")
        {
            return (mWeight / 2.205) * (0.03 / 10);
                }
        else if(mType =="Cat")
        {
            return (mWeight / 2.205) * (0.002/ 10);
        }
    }
    public double Carprofen()
    {
        if (mType == "Dog")
        {
            return (mWeight / 2.205) * (0.5 / 10);
        }
        else if (mType == "Cat")
        {
            return (mWeight / 2.205) * (0.25 / 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at those functions and see if you can figure out what they return when `mType` is something other than "Dog" or "Cat".

Comment: There is a third condition in which it's not Dog and Cat, You need to write a else statement to handle that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like  Anirudha Gupta said in the comment:
 you must have a third 'else' to handle when the type is neither a dog or cat ...
the result would be something like:

```
public double Acropromazine()
{
    if (mType == "Dog")
    {
        return (mWeight / 2.205) * (0.03 / 10);
    }
    else if (mType == "Cat")
    {
        return (mWeight / 2.205) * (0.002 / 10);
    }
    else throw new NotSupportedException("only cats and dogs support Acropromazine");
}
```